# What is known about $n$ independent random variables that yield a "converse" to uniform sample of a coordinate from a surface of an $n$-sphere?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, probability-theory, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry

It's well-known that to sample a coordinate $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ from a surface of an $n$-dimensional unit-radius sphere, it suffices to generate $n$ independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from standard normal distribution (that is, $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$), compute $S=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$, and then normalize each $X_i$ by $\sqrt{S}$ to yield each coordinate $Y_i=X_i/\sqrt{S}$.  This is due to the rotational symmetry of a joint distribution of a $n$ i.i.d. normal variables.

I am wondering about the "converse" result to this method.  The following question was posed in [this paper by Marsaglia from 1972](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-43/issue-2/Choosing-a-Point-from-the-Surface-of-a-Sphere/10.1214/aoms/1177692644.full) (see the discussion of Method 2):

> If independent $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ lead to $(X_1/\sqrt{S},\ldots,X_n/\sqrt{S})$  with a uniform distribution on a sphere, what can be said about the distributions of the $X_i$'s?

I am wondering if that question was answered (references to appropriate literature would be great).  Are $X_i$'s normally distributed?

**NOTE**:  The original post had the following question: "Suppose that I am given a coordinate $(Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_n)$ of a uniform sample from the surface of a unit $n$-sphere.  What is known about the distribution of $Z_i$'s, if independence between them is assumed?  Are they independently normally distributed?"  However, @Did pointed out in a comment that a uniform sample of a surface on a sphere is never i.i.d.  However, I am really interested in the answer to Marsaglia's question above, hence a revision to the question...

Comment: Your question is not Marsaglia's question. Re your question, a uniform sample from the surface of a sphere is never i.i.d.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your comment.  I've been digging into this, and finding that indeed the question that I asked originally is not what I meant to ask.  I think I am wondering about the answer to Marsaglia's question.  I'll re-write the question accordingly...